How to Fetch Data from Hono API Endpoint with Type Safety in Next.js App?
I'm currently utilizing Hono for my API endpoint in conjunction with Bun. Now, I'm building a separate app using Next.js, and I aim to fetch data from my API while ensuring type safety. My understanding is that I can achieve this using RPC. However, in the documentation, it mentions importing AppType, which I can't find in my Next.js app. Additionally, the setup involves two separate subdomains (api.example.com and portal.example.com). How can I effectively handle this scenario and implement type-safe data fetching from my Hono API endpoint within my Next.js application? Any guidance or example code snippets would be greatly appreciated.
Source: https://hono.dev/guides/rpc


I'm currently utilizing Hono for my API endpoint in conjunction with Bun. Now, I'm building a separate app using Next.js, and I aim to fetch data from my API while ensuring type safety.

You have to understand that in order to share types you will need a way to import it into your other app, so you could either publish it as a package to for example NPM or Github Packages or, which is the more common approach nowadays, setup a monorepo so the code for both apps is in the same repository (have a look at NX and Turborepo).
I haven't used Hono myself, but it looks very similar to tRPC. All you need to do is setup the type as described in the docs, then import it in your other app:
export type AppType = typeof route

Import:
import { AppType } from '.' // or wherever you're importing from, i.e. @myorg/types
import { hc } from 'hono/client'

